# Injective maps from free group on two generators

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Why are there no injective continuous maps from $F_2$ - the free group on two generators - and $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$?
Is it because the free group is uncountable but $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} $ is countable?

(I want to show there is no covering map between the figure 8 and the torus. Showing there is no injection from the free group to the cartesian product would be enough.)

Comment: Regardless, $F_2$ is not uncountable.

Comment: What is "continuous" here? What topologies are you putting? Judging by the lack of ```topology``` tag, did you mean "homomorphism", by any chance?

Comment: Right for some reason I was allowing words of infinite length.

Comment: I want to show there is no covering map between the figure 8 and the torus. Showing there is no injection from the free group to the cartesian product would be enough.

Comment: But there is an injection from $F_2$ to $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$, in fact there is a bijection, because both of them are countably infinite, i.e. both have bijections to $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 4):

There is an injective map $\phi: F_2\rightarrow\mathbb{Z\times Z}$ as both groups are countably infinite.

---

However, there is no injective *homomorphism* from $F_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ because there are two-generated groups which are non-abelian ($S_3$ is a good example). This proves that the figure-of-eight does not cover the torus.

That is, if there exists an injective homomorphism $\phi:F_2\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Z\times Z}$ then $F_2$ would be abelian (why?). On the other hand, by the universal property of free groups, we have a surjective homomorphism $F_2\twoheadrightarrow S_3$, so $F_2$ cannot be abelian. Hence, there is no injection $\phi$.